# How to decrypt cCryptoGS (CryptoJS) string using OpenSSL?

Tags: google-apps-script, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

Sample function in **[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)** using the **[cCryptoGS library](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs/edit)**:

```
function encrypt() {

  let message = "Hello world!";
  let pw = "password";

  let encrypted = cCryptoGS.CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, pw).toString();

  Logger.log(encrypted);

  // Sample result, changes each time due to the salt
  // U2FsdGVkX19A/TPmx/tmR9MRiKU9AQPhUYKD/lyoY/c=

};
```

Trying to decrypt using **OpenSSL:**

```
echo "U2FsdGVkX19A/TPmx/tmR9MRiKU9AQPhUYKD/lyoY/c=" | openssl enc -d -a -A -aes-256-cbc -iter 1 -md md5 -pass pass:'password' && echo
```

That command returned an **error:**

```
bad decrypt
803B3E80A67F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:
```

OpenSSL version is `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)`.

**How could the cyphertext generated by cCryptoGS be decrypted using OpenSSL?**

Comment: Interoperability with OpenSSL is described in the CryptoJS documentation section of the same name: [Interoperability](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#interoperability).

Comment: Tried that on cCryptoGS, did not work. Both of these: `cCryptoGS.CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(s, p).toString();` and `decodeURIComponent(cCryptoGS.CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(s, p).toString().replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[0-9a-f]{2}/g, '%$&'));`.

Comment: In the OpenSSL statement, add the `-md md5` option and `-A` (i.e. `-base64 -A`). OpenSSL has changed the default digest as of v1.1.0 to SHA-256, while CryptoJS still uses MD5 (maybe this is the problem). For [`-A`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html) see the *enc* documentation. If the problems persist post your OpenSSL statement and your OpenSSL version.

Comment: `echo "U2FsdGVkX19A/TPmx/tmR9MRiKU9AQPhUYKD/lyoY/c=" | openssl enc -d -a -A -aes-256-cbc -iter 1 -md md5 -pass pass:'password' && echo`. Result: `bad decrypt
803B3E80A67F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:`

Comment: Remove `-iter 1` in your OpenSSL statement, as this implicitly applies PBKDF2 as key derivation function instead of the old `EVP_BytesToKey()` used by CryptoJS, s. online here: https://onlinegdb.com/BC_tPP_S3

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help. You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key material is passed as string, it is interpreted as password and CryptoJS performs an OpenSSL compatible key derivation. For this purpose, CryptoJS implements under the hood the OpenSSL proprietary key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` with MD5 as digest. Therefore, decryption with OpenSSL is possible with the following statement:

```bash
echo "U2FsdGVkX19A/TPmx/tmR9MRiKU9AQPhUYKD/lyoY/c=" | openssl enc -d -a -A -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -pass pass:'password'
```

Be aware that OpenSSL originally used MD5 as default digest, but as of v1.1.0 it applies SHA-256. In contrast, CryptoJS uses MD5 exclusively. Therefore, for OpenSSL versions *before* v1.1.0, the *-md md5* option can be omitted.

---

**A more secure alternative**

The OpenSSL statement posted in the comment contains the *-iter 1* option. This option sets the iteration count and defines as key derivation function *implicitly* PBKDF2 (so it is equivalent to *-iter 1 -pbkdf2*, see [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html)). This is the reason why decryption fails.

However, PBKDF2 is more secure. The deprecated key derivation `EVP_BytesToKey()` is considered insecure since it uses the broken digest MD5 and an iteration count of only 1, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139). More modern OpenSSL CLI versions issue a warning accordingly:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
```

PBKDF2, on the other hand, is a reliable key derivation function that is also supported by CryptoJS. Therefore, PBKDF2 should be used for security reasons.

Unfortunately, for the built-in key derivation, CryptoJS does not support out-of-the-box switching from one key derivation function to the other. The built-in key derivation internally calls [`OpenSSLKdf.execute()`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/cipher-core.js#L750), which uses `EVP_BytesToKey()`. Therefore, a corresponding function must be implemented (called `OpenSSLPbkdf2` in the following) that applies PBKDF2, e.g.:

```js
var OpenSSLPbkdf2 = {
    execute: function(password, keySize, ivSize, salt, hasher) {
        if (!salt) {
            salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(8);
        }
        var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, pbkdf2Params);
        var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(key.words.slice(keySize), ivSize * 4);
        key.sigBytes = keySize * 4;
        return CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ key: key, iv: iv, salt: salt });
    }
};
```

and which is specified in `AES.encrypt()`/`AES.decrypt()` with `{kdf: OpenSSLPbkdf2}`. `pbkdf2Params` sets the PBKDF2 parameters (digest, iteration count and keysize). The iteration count should be as high as possible while maintaining acceptable performance. The recommended digest is SHA-256 (the OpenSSL default digest as of v1.1.0).

Example:

```js
var pbkdf2Params = {
    hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,
    iterations: 10000,
    keySize: (256 + 128)/32,
};        

var OpenSSLPbkdf2 = {
    execute: function(password, keySize, ivSize, salt, hasher) {
        if (!salt) {
            salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(8);
        }
        var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, pbkdf2Params);
        var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(key.words.slice(keySize), ivSize * 4);
        key.sigBytes = keySize * 4;
        return CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ key: key, iv: iv, salt: salt });
    }
};

var password = 'password';
var plaintext = 'Hello world!';

// Encryption
var ciphertextParams = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, password, {kdf: OpenSSLPbkdf2});
console.log(ciphertextParams.toString());

// Decryption (ciphertext in OpenSSL format)
var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextParams.toString(), password, {kdf: OpenSSLPbkdf2});
console.log(dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

// Decryption (ciphertext as CipherParams object)
var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextParams, password, {kdf: OpenSSLPbkdf2});
console.log(dec.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

The data generated in this way can be decrypted with the following OpenSSL statement:

```bash
echo "U2FsdGVkX1+K5JPuhBTtQdvUzcfvu2rbFNuBq2QTDzI=" | openssl enc -d -a -A -aes-256-cbc -iter 10000 -md sha256 -pass pass:'password'
```

this time without warning.

Comment: Awesome complete answer. I like to workaround to make it secure. Thanks a lot!